# Searching for visible and invisible system files gives no results

Tags: finder, spotlight, macos, indexing

I'm running a search and I have selected File Visibility: Visibile and Invisible and also System Files: Are included.

[image]

Yet when I search for either `ssh` or `.ssh` either by name or everything:
[image]

it fails to find the `~/.ssh` folder which is definitely there (I have set the finder to show invisible files):

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Spotlight probably never indexed it in the first place, as by default it doesn't index invisible or system areas. I'd use [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) instead if you regularly need to search in those areas.